# Jquerymobile footer moves

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I use jquerymobile for an android phonegap app. I want to create a footer that sticks to the bottom of the screen (so it's displayed all the time), even when you have to scroll on a page. Now this is working half. When I test it in the emulator scroll down on a page and click on the screen (with the mouse) the headers jumps up (see an example: http://tinyurl.com/pdv6nlp and http://tinyurl.com/p6xycr9

My code is very basic:

```
<div data-role="page" id="blog" style="background-image:url(img/bg_hdpi.png); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:top center; background-attachment:scroll; background-color:#d7d8d8;">


<div data-role="content">   
    <div id="contentTXT">
        <div id="outputblog"></div>
        <img src="img/spacer.gif" height="60" width="100">
    </div>  
</div><!-- /content -->

<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" >
    <div style="float:left;"><a href="#" onclick="history.back(); return false">back</a></div>
    <div style="float:right;"><a href="#foo" data-transition="flip">home</a></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Try this fix when you click `$($.mobile.activePage).trigger('updatelayout');`.

Comment: do you mean somewhere in the header? This is not chancing anything when I place this in the header: <script language="javascript">
 $($.mobile.activePage).trigger('updatelayout');
 </script>

Comment: No, on click event. `$('body').on('click', function () { the code above });`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple lines of CSS should fix that right up:

```
position:fixed; 
bottom:0;
```

Used inline with your footer div:

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" style="position:fixed;bottom:0;">
```

Comment: position:fixed should be avoided because on older phones, web views do not understand fixed css rule.

Comment: Excellent, best solution so far. This saved my day.

Comment: Awesome! Saved me a headache

Answer (score 6):

If you use css position fixed that will break on older devices like blackberry, older iphones and older android, so that works only for android 4.x.

To do it properly use jquery mobile attributes, add one more tag in your footer to keep it fixed on the bottom of the screen.

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
    <div><a href="#" onclick="history.back(); return false">back</a></div>
    <div><a href="#foo" data-transition="flip">home</a></div>
</div>
```

Tap toggle will keep the footer even if you scroll or tap on the body.

Comment: `data-tap-toggle="false"` works for me. This should be the better answer.

Comment: @CarsonIp data-tap-toggle is not enough to fix the jumping footer in Android Emulator. So, this is not the better answer. The data-tap-toggle fixes the small footer jump.

Answer (score 2):

If using 1.1 or later, add data-tap-toggle="false" to your header and footer, as documented here.